# Ambethia recaptcha does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, recaptcha

I am Using Ambethia recaptcha for a voting system.I have followed all the standard guidelines.But, recaptcha is not validated.I ran console in Firebug and i got this in the response:

```
Recaptcha::RecaptchaError
    in IndicesController#increment
</h1>
<pre>uninitialized constant Recaptcha::Verify::Net</pre>
```

Is this the problem with code or is it because of webrick server?

**Edit:**
Here's my controller:

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
    def display
        @digits=Digit.all
    end

    def increment
        @digit= Digit.find(params[:id])
        if verify_recaptcha
        @digit.increment!(:value)
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
        end
       else
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js {render 'fail.js.erb'}
        end
    end
    end
end
```

here is the view:

```
<%@digits.each do |c|%>
    <h1><%=c.value%></h1>
    <p id="fail" style="display:none">Incorrect recaptcha</p>
    <p id="para" style="display:none">Succesfully Incremented</p>
    <%=recaptcha_tags%>
    <%=button_to 'Increment',increment_path(:format=>:js,:id=>c.id),:remote=>true%>
    <%end%>
```

Comment: What is "Ambethia recaptcha" ? Can you post the code you use it in your view to define your recaptcha ?

Comment: Ambethia recaptcha is the recaptcha plugin that provides helpers. I will post more information in Edit. https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use RVM, open the following file:

~/.rvm/gems/*name_of_your_gemset*/gems/ambethia-recaptcha-0.2.2/lib/recaptcha/rails.rb

And make sure you have the following two lines at the top:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'recaptcha'
```